# reactive statement that runs every time any state variable changes

Tags: state, svelte, reactive

I am trying to write a simple app. The app has two child components. Each components represents a team. The score begins from 20 and the group which loses all points 0 lost.

my parent component has two variables

```
  <script>
    let scoreA = 20
    let scoreB = 20
  </script>
```

the child components are simple counter components, which have one variable called score and increment and decrement function. I am binding the two state variables from the parent the the child components and passing the state from the child to the parent

```
<CounterComponent bind:score={scoreA} />
<CounterComponent bind:score={scoreB} />
```

I tried to make a function which constantly checks the state every time something changes using a reactive statement:

```
  <script>
    let scoreA = 20
    let scoreB = 20
    function checkState() {
      console.log(`Score A: ${scoreA}, Score B: ${scoreB}`)
    }
    $: checkState()
  </script>
```

For some reason this function only runs one time and that is it. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive dependencies are only tracked in the statement itself; because you just call a function without any arguments, it detects no dependencies.

You either have to declare the function reactively or just inline the code. You can also create reactive statements with blocks using `$: { ... }` if you need multiple statements.

Since it is just one line, you could just inline it here:

```js
$: console.log(`Score A: ${scoreA}, Score B: ${scoreB}`)
```

Keeping the function, but making it reactive:

```js
$: checkState = function () {
    console.log(`Score A: ${scoreA}, Score B: ${scoreB}`)
}
$: checkState()
```

Here the call has a transitive dependency on the scores.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and it helped me a lot to understand about reactivity.

Answer (score 0):

if you defined your function like this:

```
function checkState(x,y) {
      console.log(`Score A: ${x}, Score B: ${y}`)
    }
```

and in your reactive statement, pass `scoreA` and `scoreB` as args :

```
 $: checkState(scoreA,scoreB)
```

This should work because the state that your reactive statement dependent on must appear on the right hand side reactive declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Svelte 5, you can consider using $effect

```
<script>
let scoreA = $state(20);
let scoreB = $state(20);
$effect(() => {
   console.log(`Score A: ${scoreA}, Score B: ${scoreB}`);
   ...
   return ... ;
})
</script>
```

as per Svelte 5 Doc, logics inside the effect, before "return" runs

1. on component first mount,
2. on `scoreA` or `scoreB` alteration, after DOM update

Hope it's helpful...